Despite setting cascade: true and onDelete: 'CASCADE' on the relationship, the dependent entity is not being deleted when the parent entity is removed
In One to One relation Despite configuring cascade: true and onDelete: 'CASCADE' on the relationship, the dependent entity is still not being deleted when the parent entity is removed. I also tried specifying cascade types such as insert, update, and delete, but the issue persists.
While insertion works correctly, and both the parent (user) and the child (profile) are created, deletion only removes the parent entity (user) without deleting the associated child entity (profile). Given the cascade settings, the expected default behavior should be that both the parent and child entities are deleted when the parent entity is removed. However, the profile remains in the database, which is not the intended outcome.[![enter image description here]
I configured the relationship with cascade: true and onDelete: 'CASCADE', expecting that when the parent entity (user) is deleted, the associated dependent entity (profile) would also be removed automatically. Additionally, I experimented with different cascade types—such as insert, update, and delete—to ensure that all relevant operations would propagate between the related entities.
note: i am using neon+Postgres
code :
// user.entity.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Profile } from './profile.entity';
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

@Entity()
export class User{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number

    @Column({unique:true,nullable:false})
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEmail()
    email:string;

    @Column()
    password:string;

    @OneToOne(()=>Profile,(profile)=>profile.user,{cascade:true,onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    @JoinColumn()
    profile:Profile;
}


// profile.entity.ts

import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';


@Entity()
export class Profile{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column({nullable:true})
    name:string

    @Column({nullable:true})
    bio:string;

    @OneToOne(()=>User,(user)=>user.profile)
    user:User;
}


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. add your [mre] as formatted text instead.

i removed screenshots of my code

Use psql and see what the actual table structure in the database is. My suspicion is you have something backwards.

Thanks for your suggestion! I’ve made a few changes to my code and updated the question accordingly. If you have a moment, could you please take another look? I’d really appreciate your feedback to see if I’ve set something up incorrectly.

In order to let someone know you 've left a message, put@in front of their nane/avatar!

@AdrianKlaver .I've updated the question accordingly. If you have a moment, could you please take another look? I’d really appreciate your feedback to see if I’ve set something up incorrectly.

This question is similar to: TypeORM Cascade Delete. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't see an update that indicates what the table structure in the database is.

Resolved! Thank you, @AdrianKlaver .Your insights helped me identify the issue.

Here, Profile is the parent entity, and User is the child. With this structure, deleting the child (User) without deleting the parent (Profile) is allowed, as it doesn't break any constraints.so removing User does not remove its parent (Profile).
However, if User was set as the parent and Profile as the child, using .remove on the User entity would trigger a foreign key constraint error. This happens because the default behavior attempts to delete User before Profile, leading to a violation of the foreign key constraint.
To handle this, you need to delete the child (Profile) explicitly before deleting the parent (User). Here’s how you can structure the delete method to respect this order:
updated:
  //user.entity.ts  
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
    import { Profile } from "./profile.entity";
    
    
    @Entity()
    export class Users{
    
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id:number;
    
        @Column()
        email:string;
    
        @Column()
        password:string;
    
        @OneToOne(()=>Profile,(profile)=>profile.user)
        profile:Profile;
    }

//profile.entity.ts  
    
    import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
    import { Users } from "./users.entity";
    
    
    
    @Entity()
    export class Profile{
    
    
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id:number;
    
        @Column({nullable:true})
        bio:string;
    
        @Column({nullable:true})
        name:string;
    
        @OneToOne(()=>Users,(user)=>user.profile,{cascade:true,orphanedRowAction: 'delete' ,nullable:false})
        @JoinColumn()
        user:Users;
    }
    
    
    //user.service.ts
        async delete(id: number) {
          const user = await this.userRepos.findOne({
            where: { id },
            relations: ['profile'], // Load related profile
          });
        
          if (!user) {
            throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
          }
        
          // First, remove the associated profile
          await this.profileRepos.remove(user.profile);
        
          // Then, remove the user
          await this.userRepos.remove(user);
        
          return "Deletion successful";
        }

